# How to use installed certificate on my own Android App?

Tags: android, ssl

I'm developing an Android App and I want to use a digital certificate installed on my device. I have a function which can sign a pdf document using a path, p.e. /sdcard/Downloads. In this case, I can use that certificate but when I install it, I don't know where it is.

Does everyone know if Android has an API to access it? Or what is the path of the certificate?

Comment: I have a pfx certificate and I install it using a password.

Comment: Can I sign pdf from my app using digital certificate?